# How to use custom font in iMovie on OSX

Tags: macos, font, imovie

I've been trying to use a custom `.TTF` font on OSX to watermark videos edited in iMovie. But there doesn't seem to be any option at all.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you installed the font properly (e.g. is it available in the font collection)?

Answer (score 4):

**First: Install the font:**

1. Open application **Font Book**
2. Copy your .TFF font and paste it into the application (or drag and drop)

**Second: Change font in iMovie:**

If you're in iMovie and you have a textbox, select the text you want its font to change and hit **Command + T**. The font selection popup opens and you should be able to select your installed font.